# Amazon Kindle Fire won't allow allow links in PDFs to work

Tags: kindle, pdf

On my Kindle Fire I opened the PDF via the silk browser.
The PDF contains links. On my iOS device I can click on the links in the PDF.
On my Kindle Fire the links don't work.